# Does Haskell do a default conversion from double to integer?

Tags: haskell, type-conversion

I have a function that has the type `Int -> Int -> Int -> Int`. When i use `div a b` as a value for a variable in the function it seems, that the value gets rounded down to 0 if the return of `div a b` is 1/2 or anything double like.

Is this correct? Does Haskell cut of values like in java, if a double is forced into an integer?

Comment: `div` has nothing to do with real numbers of any kind, or rounding anything. It is the integer division function. It is defined entirely in terms of integers.

Comment: see also `mod` and `divMod` (and also `quot`, `rem`, and `quotRem`)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`div 1 2` doesn't return 0.5, which is then converted to the integer 0. It returns 0 in the first place. `div` performs integer division and as such always returns an integer (or other Integral type depending on which type you used it with). There's no doubles involved.

When you do convert a double to an integer, the method of rounding depends on which method you used. For example `floor` would round the number down whereas `round` would round to the nearest integer. There are no implicit conversions in Haskell, so any conversion will happen through a function.

Answer (score 3):

> Does Haskell cut off values like in java

no it does not.

When doing **integer division**, Java rounds *towards zero*, whereas Haskell rounds *downwards*; so in Haskell

```
\> (-9) `div` 10
-1
```

whereas in Java `-9 / 10` is zero:

```java
public class IntDiv{
     public static void main(String []args){
         double a = (-9) / 10;
         System.out.printf("%.2f\n", a); // would print 0.00
     }
}
```

Comment: You may want to mention that ``(-9) `quot` 10`` behaves like Java, returning 0.